# How to send different keys each time a button is pressed?

Tags: autohotkey

So i got this code:

```
Chars:= ["5","6"] , cnt:= 0

Lbutton::
    Send % Chars[cnt:= ++cnt>chars.MaxIndex() ? 1 : cnt]
    KeyWait, Lbutton    
Return
```

Its working fine.

If i hit the Left Mouse Button, its gonna send the 5 key.

If i hit it again its gonna send the 6 key and its start again.

BUT what i want is that the keys are toogle until i let go the Left Mouse Button.

Its for a game tho. :D

Comment: What do you mean by "**toogle**"?? I wouldn't understand it if you meant "**toggled**", either. You'd like 5 and 6 to be repeated?

Comment: hey thx for the comment. yeah english is not my bright side sry :D anyway
i mean i want them to be hold down as i hold down my left mouse button.
and want them to be released when i let go my left mouse button. the sequence should be the same.

right now if i hold down my LMB it still send just one 5 or one 6.

Comment: so when i hold down the left mouse button it should hold down the 5 key or the 6 key not just hit it once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As specified [here](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#Parameters), this will keep the key held down until you release the LMB:

```
Chars := ["5", "6"]
, cnt := 0

LButton::Send % "{" Chars[cnt := ++cnt > chars.MaxIndex() ? 1 : cnt] " Down}"
LButton Up::Send % "{" Chars[cnt] " Up}"
```